# How to use angularJs validation on year?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have one input text field that takes Year value.
I used 
`ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{4}$/"` for enter year value in 4 digit.But How can I check input year is between from 1950 to current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) using `min` and `max` validation

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NK3E1D60IoSUlKwjVCve?p=preview)

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
    <form name="form">
      <input type="number" ng-model="year" name="year" min="1950" max="{{vm.currentYear}}"> <br/>
      <span ng-if="form.year.$error.min">Year should be at least 1950</span>
      <span ng-if="form.year.$error.max">Year can not be in the future!</span>
    </form>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', []).controller("Ctrl", function() {
        this.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

This will set the `min` or`max` validation `$error` key on `year` in case someone enters a year that is not within these bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value" min="1950" max="{{currentYear}}">
```

Comment: You forgot `name` and `ng-model` attributes. No validation will happen without these